# Laravel migrate:rollback adding and deleting table columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, migration, database-migration

I have used the `php artisan migrate:make add_something_to_to_user_table --table=users`

and coded

```
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->string('description1');
        $table->string('description2');
        $table->string('description3');
    });
```

and added three fields and gave `php artisan migrate` and the fields got stored in to the database

also found that the `migration table` is updated with the row `2014_11_05_145536_add_something_to_to_user_table`

now when i use `php artisan migrate:rollback`

The `2014_11_05_145536_add_something_to_to_user_table` row in the migration table is missing but the columns added to the **users table** remains the same

**why it is not deleting the fields in the table also** which results in error while using `php artisan migrate` again...

Comment: Have you correctly setup the `down()` method in your migration class?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should have a `down()` method in you migration that should look like this:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table)
    {
        $table->dropColumn(array('description1', 'description2', 'description3'));
    });
}
```

That will be called on rollback and will take care of removing the columns added by the migration.

Comment: should I have to mention all columns in the `up()` function in `down()` also in the same file??

Comment: Yes they should be in the same file. In a migration class the `up` method will apply the changes and the `down` method will undo them.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you already ran the `artisan migrate:rollback` command and you didn't have the `down` method setup you'll have to remove the columns manually before reruning the migration (that's why you got errors when trying to call `migrate`, because it tried to add the 3 columns when they already exist).

Comment: so if i want to delete one column i must delete in `up()` and add in `down()` is that right??

Comment: Exactly. In `up` you setup the changes you want and in `down` you do the exact opposite.

Comment: pls provide several ways to `add array` as like you mentioned for `drop array` in this answer

Comment: You mean to add multiple columns from an array? Instead of having to define each one on a separate line? That's not possible. Check the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns) for more info on the Schema Builder.

Answer (score 2):

According to laravel 7+ doc this will also work when you need to drop multiple columns at the same time.

```php
public function down(){
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->dropColumn(['description1', 'description2', 'description3']);
   });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Add **down** public function to drop **users** table when rollback..

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```